# Mark files in directory as favorite (Ubuntu Desktop)

Tags: file-management, ubuntu, photography

## Introduction

I have a digital camera since 15 years. My son is 13 now and we want to create a book with photos of his childhood.

This means my wife and me we need to select our favorite photos.

I look at the directories with nautilus. After hitting "ctrl +" the images are big enough, so that we can scan the directories with our human eyes easily.

## Question

There seems to be no way to mark a file as favorite in nautilus.

Is there a alternative software which can do this?

## Required featured

- Should work on Ubuntu Desktop
- Open Source
- Easy way to tag/mark files in a directory
- It should be usable for my wife and my mum (Creating symlinks is no solution).

## Background

There are a lot of photos (76k). Stored in the structure YYYY/YYYY-MM/YYYY-MM-DD. There are 2k directories.

Any recoommendation?

## General Purpose Solution Prevered

I would like to have a general purpose solution. This time I need to select images in a directory. Maybe I need to select ogg/mp3 the next time :-)

Comment: In general you could create a link (shortcut) to the favourite files and put them all in some directory? I think that's generally how windows' recently used folder worked

Comment: I'd swear that Nautilus had a way to tag or label files or colors or icons ("emblems"), but it's been years since I last used GNOME.

Comment: @Kodiologist what do you use now? Does your desktop support my use case?

Comment: @guettli These days, I do most of my file management on the command line. I use LXDE, which has PCManFM as its native file manager, but PCManFM doesn't seem to have a feature like this.

Comment: @Kodiologist I love the command line. Unfortunately this does not work here, since I need to look at the images.